# change textposition of colourbar in scale_color_discrete

Tags: r, colors, ggplot2

I generate the legend in my ggplot2 plot with

```
scale_colour_discrete(name=textCF)
```

I like that i can see which colour belongs to which value, but it consumes to much space in the plot.

[image: legend does not fit]

I tried also the `scale_colour_gradientn` scheme, but this is so condensed, that i can not distiguish the values anymore. If i could only change the width of this colourbar.

```
scale_colour_gradientn(name=textCF,colours = rainbow(nrow(mydf), start=2/6), breaks=round(mydf$CF)) +
```

[image: ticks are to close]

How can I improve the lookout?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The size of a colourbar can be controlled with the `barwidth` and `barheight` parameters.

Start with a reproducible example to see the effects:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient() +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]

I'm using `scale_colour_gradient`, but this works in general.

You control aspects of the guide with the `guide` argument to a scale. See the help on `guide_colourbar` for all the parameters that you can set.

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=wt, y=mpg, colour=qsec)) +
  geom_point() +
  scale_colour_gradient(guide = guide_colourbar(barwidth=20, barheight=2)) +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")
```

[image]